# Training on classes in sequence

Tags: neural-networks, dataset

What is the effect of training my data, lets say with 5 classes (a,b,c,d,e), we train in mini-batches and we train the model on all the data for class 'a' then 'b' and so on. 
I'd like to know the general effect of this when using DNN's, ACAM's and RNN's?

I expect an answer will be "it's not worth the risk when randomizing data is so easy"... so let's say that (hypothetically) due to time considerations I'm likely to receive the data for each class, day's apart and training on each class takes a day and the sooner this thing is done the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the problem with this approach is that you are episodically training the network to say: "Everything belongs to class X". This is easy to learn; actually, it is enough to adjust the bias in the last layer for unit representing class "X" to make the network give correct predictions. Once the next episode starts with another class "Y", the network may simply re-adjust its biases and give correct predictions again.

What you really want is to distinguish between various classes. To make that possible, **the network needs to see various classes to learn how to differentiate between them**.

In your scenario, you could always wait until you have data for at least two classes before you start training, and add more data with other classes later as they arrive.